# Disable a cell depending on value in another cell (jqgrid)

Tags: drop-down-menu, jqgrid

I have a grid with a subgrid, editable as cellEdit. In this subgrid I have one column that is a dropdownlist. What I want to do is disable inmediately two other cells in the grid (only in the same column) if the selected value of the list is "LIBRE". 
I'm doing as follows (in the subgrid definition part):

```
afterEditCell:function(id, cellname, value, iRow, iCol){
          var grid=jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_idHilos);
          var ret = jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_idHilos).jqGrid('getRowData',id);


        if(ret.nombreestadoe1=="LIBRE"){
            grid.jqGrid('setCell',id,'conectadoe1','','not-editable-cell');
            grid.jqGrid('setCell',id,'puertohiloe1','','not-editable-cell');                    

        }
        else if(ret.nombreestadoe1!="LIBRE"){
            var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,"conectadoe1"),
            tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(id), 
            td = tr.cells[iCol];
            $(td).removeClass("not-editable-cell");

            iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,"puertohiloe1"),
            tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(id),
            td = tr.cells[iCol];
            $(td).removeClass("not-editable-cell");


        }}
```

The thing is: it is working, but only after clicking two times in different cells, and that's because right after the selected value is changed, the content of ret.nombreestadoe1 is:

```
<select role="select" id="10_nombreestadoe1" name="nombreestadoe1"><option style="background-color: green;" value="1" role="option">LIBRE</option><option style="background-color: red;" value="2" role="option">OCUPADO</option><option style="background-color: purple;" value="3" role="option">ROTO</option><option style="background-color: grey;" value="0" role="option">SIN DEFINIR</option></select>
```

After clicking somewhere else, it works fine, as the right value is already set in the list.

How can I get what it was just selected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found what to do. First, I do it in the 'change' function in dataevents of the column where the first list is. This way I get the selected value inmediately, I check it, and depending on the value, I disable the cell with the same code. Here the code:

```
{name:"nombreestadoe1",stype:'select',searchoptions:    {dataUrl:'json/estadosHilos.jsp',searchhidden:true},editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:    {dataUrl:'json/estadosHilos.jsp',
                 dataEvents: [
               { type: 'change', fn: function(e) {
                        var grid=jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_idHilos);
                        var id=grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

                        switch (e.currentTarget.selectedIndex){
                        case  0:
                                color="green";                                       
                                grid.jqGrid('setCell',id,'conectadoe1','','not-editable-cell');
                                grid.jqGrid('setCell',id,'puertohiloe1','','not-editable-cell');                                     
                                break;
                        case 1:
                                color="red";                                        
                                break;
                        case 2: 
                                color="purple";                                       
                                break;
                        case 3: 
                                color="grey";                                       
                                break;
                        default: 
                                color="white";                                       
                                break;
                    }
                    if(color!="green"){
                        var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,"conectadoe1"),
                        tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(id), 
                        td = tr.cells[iCol];
                        $(td).removeClass("not-editable-cell");
                        iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,"puertohiloe1"),
                        tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(id),
                        td = tr.cells[iCol];
                        $(td).removeClass("not-editable-cell");
                    }

                    e.currentTarget.parentElement.style.backgroundColor=color;

                    }},
                ]},index:"nombreestadoe1",width:70,hidden:false
            },
```